# How @RequestBody works

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa, jpa-2.0

How to get more details:

I am doing simple rest post request from Postman chrome extension.

My controller is :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/theme")
public class ThemeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody
    Status addTheme(@RequestBody Theme theme) {
        try {
            themeServices.addEntity(theme);
            return new Status(1, "Theme added Successfully !");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
            return new Status(0, e.toString());
        }

    }
```

In Theme.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "theme", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "theme_id" }) })
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
@NamedQuery(name = "Theme.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM Theme t")
public class Theme implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "theme_id")
    private long themeId;

    private String description;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable=true)
    private ThemeCategory themeCategory;
```

In ThemeCategory.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "theme_category", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "category_id" }) })
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
@NamedQuery(name = "ThemeCategory.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM ThemeCategory t")
public class ThemeCategory implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "category_id")
    private long categoryId;

    private String description;

    private String name;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Theme
    // @OneToMany(mappedBy="themeCategory")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "themeCategory", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Column(nullable = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Theme> themes;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to ThemeCategory
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_category_id", nullable=true)
    @JsonBackReference
    private ThemeCategory parentThemeCategory;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to ThemeCategory
    // @OneToMany(mappedBy="themeCategory")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentThemeCategory", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Column(nullable = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<ThemeCategory> themeCategories;
```

Theme Category Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `theme_category` (
  `category_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_category_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL ,
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`),
  KEY `idx_parent_category_id` (`parent_category_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_parent_category_id` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_category_id`) REFERENCES `theme_category` (`category_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=301 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Theme Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `theme` (
  `theme_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `file_path` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`theme_id`),
  KEY `idx_category_id` (`category_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_category_id` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `theme_category` (`category_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=401 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I am using Postman extension to do a rest post call:

http://localhost:8080/CustomerRegistration/theme/create

Header params:

Content-Type: application/json

Json Body:

```
{"description":"theme8","name":"theme8","themeCategory":{"categoryId":302, "themes":[],"parentThemeCategory":{}, "themeCategories":[]}}
```

And tried around 2 hours with multiple ways of body. But it consistently saying:

> The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported
>   by the requested resource for the requested method.

To analyse, I am not getting any thing else. In Eclipse console also not showing anything regarding the this issue.

What is wrong? Is there any tools to create valid requests.

Comment: I tried your code, with your same request and it works. The unique difference is that Im using "Advance Rest Client" for sending the request.

Comment: There is Theme_Category table having onetomany relationship between category and theme entities. which maintain theme categories and themes.  Might be that reason I posted all code in https://github.com/Ravikumarmaddi/UserRegistration/tree/master/UserRegistration   Kindly look it.

Comment: Add an Accept header for application/json, and try again